# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException when using Jaxb unmarshal/marshal

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm using JAXB to unmarshal a given input Xml file into Java object 
and then marashal it back to Xml String.
My Xml file looks like this:

```
<bpmn2:definitions xmlns:bpmn2="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" id="_Definitions_1">
    <bpmn2:process id="_500441" name="process">
    </bpmn2:process>
</bpmn2:definitions>
```

**Definitions.class:**

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL")
public class Definitions {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlElement(name = "bpmn2:process")
    private Process process;

    @XmlElement(name = "bpmndi:BPMNDiagram")
    private Diagram diagram;

    public Definitions() {
    }
    public Definitions(String id, Process process, Diagram diagram) {
        this.id = id;
        this.process = process;
        this.diagram = diagram;
    }
    public Process getProcess() {
        return process;
    }
    public Diagram getDiagram() {
        return diagram;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

**Process.class:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Process {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;
    public Process() {
    }
    public Process(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

**Model.class:**

```
public class Model {
    @XmlElement
    private Process process;
    public Model() {
    }
    public Model(String processId, Process p) {
        this.id = processId;
        this.process = p;
    }
}
```

**main method:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException, JAXBException {
        BpmnToJsonImport bj = new BpmnToJsonImport();
        InputStream is = BpmnToJsonImport.class.getResourceAsStream("myXml.txt");
        String Str = IOUtils.toString(is);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(Str);
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Definitions.class, Model.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

        Definitions d = (Definitions) unmarshaller.unmarshal(sr);
        Model model = new Model(d.getProcess().getId(), d.getProcess());

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        marshaller.marshal(model, sw);
        String str = sw.toString();
        System.out.println(str);

    }
```

Exactly when it tries to retrieve the process id using d.getProcess.getId I get the 
 **java.lang.NullPointerException**

Comment: Try using the fully qualified path for your XML file. For example: C:\MyFolder\myXml.txt 
It could be that myXml.txt is not found. If it is found, it could be that your "Process.class" does not have a "name" field?

Comment: the problem is not with the file becouse when I do: System.out.println(d.getId()) it gives me the id of bpmn2:definitions. I don't need the name field

Comment: You've got a number of issues here. Model.java doesn't compile, and you haven't provided the Diagram class. I was able to get past your error by removing the "bpmn2" namespace qualifier from definitions.class, so from that I'd say you have annotation errors somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mapping the namespace qualification incorrectly.  You must not include the prefix in the element name.

```
@XmlElement(name = "BPMNDiagram")
private Diagram diagram;
```

To map the namespace qualification you can use the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation.

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace =  "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: I solved the problem for process specifing the namespace as you suggested, but I get the same error for BPMNDiagram for which I have to use another namespace "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI". I tried this way @XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL", elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, xmlns = {
  @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "bpmn2", namespaceURI = "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"),
  @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "bpmndi", namespaceURI = "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI")}) 
but it doesn't worked